# Prevent controller to start, if $rootScope.projects is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am sending `HTTP` request on the `app.run` part of the angular application. But the problem is that controller that uses `$rootScope.projects` is started before `$rootScope.projects` was created and filled by the `HTTP` request.

How can I prevent controller to load if `$rootScope.projects` is undefined?

Here is my `HTTP` request:

```
$http({method : 'GET', url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Project', 
        headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':ParseID, 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':ParseREST}})
    .success(function(res) {
        $rootScope.projects = res.results;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        $rootScope.projects = [];
    });
```

Comment: are you using `ui-router`? If so, `resolve` comes to mind for doing stuff like this before controller instantiation

Comment: You could manually bootstrap your angular application once your server side data has been retrieved in the AJAX callback: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data

Comment: You can also init the projects variable to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over controller instantiation time when using `ng-controller`. Use one-time watch

```
var initWatcher = $rootScope.$watch('projects', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    initWatcher();
    // init further 
  }
})
```

in controller - or emit 'init' event on $rootScope and listen for it.

If ngRoute/ui-router is the case, you can use route's `resolve` which is intended exactly for such things.